# How do option exchanges make money on profitable long call?

Tags: options, stock-exchanges

When invoking a profitable long call as a trader, how does the options exchange (eg: NASDAQ) make any money?

Per my understanding, the only "fees" that I pay is the premium for purchashing the stock initially. However, that must be largely offset by the buy order the exchange would have to place when the trader invokes the option.

So how does the exchange make money? Is there a corresponding long put for every long call?

Comment: no no, the price you pay (including so-called "premium" - or whatever) is entirely paid to the human you bought the contract from!!  Nasdaq makes money by charging a very small fee on each transaction to your brokerage.  (They additionally make money from stuff like "selling data".)  Note that "premium" is just a word used by some mathematicians to describe the nature of the price you pay.  The only reality is the "price you pay".  If I understood your question correctly, cheers

Comment: The question isn't well worded and I initially misunderstood it.  'Invoking' and option should be 'exercising'. And if one is exercising the call, it's not an 'option exchange' such as the NASDAQ where the equity transaction takes place.

Answer (score 1):

To clear up a few things: Exercising a call does not execute a "buy order" on the exchange. Your option trade is with another counterparty who presumable *already has* stock to sell you at that price. In other words, your option contract is not with the *exchange* who must then buy stock (and pay commissions), it's with another counterparty that already *has* the stock.  At worst, they must *buy* the stock to cover their option, which then creates *another* fee from the exchange (similarly, they aren't buying the stock from the exchange, but from someone else *through* the exchange).

> So how does the exchange make money?

Various ways, but the bigger ones are:

- Transaction fees (passed through by brokers)
- Membership fees (to allow direct trading)
- Subscriptions to data that they generate (order books, prices, etc.)

Comment: Exercising a call may or may not executes a "buy order".  If the counterparty does not own the stock, he either goes short or he buys the stock on the exchange to deliver the shares to the call exerciser.  Commissions go to the broker.  The add on regulatory fee goes to the SEC. The B/A spread goes to the market maker.  While the exchange may receive an overall access fee from the broker or a 'membership' fee from the market maker,  AFAIK, exchanges do not receive any portion of these. And then there are all of these 'discount' brokers who charge no commission.  What's to share? Nada  :->)

Answer (score 1):

Exchanges make money in a myriad of ways but  not in the way that you suggest.  For details, google for the annual financial report for an exchange such as the CBOE, NASDAQ, NYSE, etc.

An exchange is where securities are listed.  A broker is an intermediary that sends your order to an exchange or ECN.

In order for you to buy your long call, there must be a counterparty willing to sell that call to you.  Ignoring commissions (if you're still paying them) and fees, option trading is a zero sum game.  What one trader makes, the  trader on the other side loses.

When you exercise your long call to buy the stock, someone who is short the call is assigned and must sell you the stock at the strike price.  If he owns the stock, it is sold to you.  If he doesn't own the stock, his broker borrows the stock from a third party to sell and the trader  becomes short the stock.  If the stock isn't borrowable, the trader is forced to buy the stock in order to deliver it to you.